# Which drivers are necessary for an AF Drive in an HP laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, chipset

I have a HP Pavillion HP DV4-2126TX.

Since the hard drive crashed, I bought a new drive and it is an AF drive.The company website tells me to install some drivers from Intel but HP has not listed those drivers. Which of them should I download and why?

I mean, storage drivers And what about other drivers? Should I download all? The link is given [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=in&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4168972)

I also want to avoid **Bloatware** and what about the chipset drivers. Clean Install from a bootable USB. Win7 Home Premium 32bit

Comment: Not enough information, need full HP product number of the lappy, which OS you are installing, and are you going to use the HP recovery media. More than likely you need sata drivers, but without a Full HP product number it could be one of many to choose from. Edit your question to include these 3 items.

Comment: what's an "AF" drive?

Comment: Advanced Format is a generic term pertaining to any sector format used to store data on the magnetic disks in hard disk drives that exceeds 512 to 520 bytes per sector.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any specific drivers for an AF drive. Just the essentials

- Chipset
- Audio
- Matrix storage driver
- Turbo Boost
- Realtek card driver, if your laptop has a SD card slot
- Relevant graphics & audio drivers